# How do screensavers support multiple monitors?

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors, screensaver

If i were developing a screensaver using a windows.form in C# how would i support multiple monitors? obviously i need a way to enumerate the monitors and maybe create forms for them too or just fade to black? Has anyone solved this?

Any insight would be helpful, what's the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [this article from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/scrframework.aspx) it helped me create my first screen saver and talks about multiple monitor support.

`System.Windows.Forms.Screen` class has all the information you need about how many monitors and what the bounds of those monitors are. The property `AllScreens` would be a good place to start.

`for (int i = Screen.AllScreens.GetLowerBound(0); i <= Screen.AllScreens.GetUpperBound(0); i++)

{

    ScreensaverFormList[i].Bounds = Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds;

}`